# C#/.NET - How to trigger update of listview from another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, listview

It seems I'm forbidden to access (i.e. update) my list view control from another thread than the main thread.

How can I perform some threaded task and then signal somehow to start the update of the listview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call Invoke() to make the change.

The reason why is explained here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/davidklinems/archive/2006/03/09/548235.aspx

How to do it with an example is shown here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx

Basically the changes have to be done from the main thread, so you have to get back on that to do your update.